# onStateChange is called multiple times in atmosphere framework

Tags: java, atmosphere

I'm using the **atmosphere** framework in my application.

https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere

I've extended the AbstractReflectorAtmosphereHandler class and implemented the

```
-onRequest
-destroy
-onstatechanged
```

methods.

When a client wants to send a message to the server:

```
subSocket.push(jQuery.stringifyJSON({ data: "blahblah", source:"client" }));
```

The onRequest function is called; however the message

```
Object message = atmosphereResource.getAtmosphereResourceEvent().getMessage();
```

Is empty.

Than I tried using the onstatechanged which is called every time

```
(1) The remote connection gets closed, either by a browser or a proxy
(2) The remote connection reach its maximum idle time (AtmosphereResource.suspend))
(3) Everytime a broadcast operation is executed (broadcaster.broadcast)
```

However even after filtering out 1 and 2

```
 public void onStateChange(AtmosphereResourceEvent event)
                throws IOException {
        if (source.equals("client") && !event.isResumedOnTimeout() && !event.isResuming()){       
                    System.out.println("message form client");
                    System.out.println(message.toString());
        } else {
                //normal onstatechanged code from AbstractReflectorAtmosphereHandler
        }
```

However the message is printed randomly between 2 and 4 times. It should only be called once.

So my **question** is: Can I acces the message inside the onRequest method or why is the onStateChange called so many times.

edit: from the answer given by jF I've been able to acces the message inside the onRequest function. (I'm not sure however if that is what he actually meant).

```
public void onRequest(AtmosphereResource resource) throws IOException {
    //Object message = resource.getAtmosphereResourceEvent().getMessage(); //is empty why?

    //leave connection open
    resource.suspend();

    BufferedReader reader = resource.getRequest().getReader();
    Object message = reader.readLine();

    if (message !=null){
        System.out.println("**onRequest: "+message.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to read the request's body by doing, in your `onStateChange`:

```
atmosphereResource.getRequest().getReader (or getInputStream).
```

Comment: why do I need to read the request body? Thx you for coming here; awesome framework.

Comment: I do seem to be able to acces the message inside onRequest() trough the atmosphereResource.getRequest().getReader > str reader in > str if that's what you mean but I'm confused because you're talking about onStateChange. Merci

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helpes other people:

```
public void onRequest(AtmosphereResource resource) throws IOException { 
    //Object message = resource.getAtmosphereResourceEvent().getMessage(); //is empty why?
    //leave connection open
    resource.suspend();

    BufferedReader reader = resource.getRequest().getReader();
    Object message = reader.readLine();

    if (message !=null){
        Object obj = JSONValue.parse(message.toString());
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        Object source = jsonObject.get("source");

        System.out.println("**onRequest: "+message.toString());
        ArrayList frame = new ArrayList(); 
        frame.add(jsonObject.get("type"));
        frame.add(jsonObject.get("data"));
        writeQueue.add(frame);
    }
}
```